# Booting MX6Q SABRE LITE using SD card

Tags: boot, sd-card

I tried copying u-boot.imx file onto the SD card to complete the booting process but got certain problems with it.Can somebody explain why MX6Q SABRE LITE board can't boot from SD card directly?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all boards support to boot from USB device now. You should check the BIOS settings to see if you allow your board to boot from USB device.

You also need to make sure your SD card controller (reader) support the boot function.

Another thing you need to notice is you must make the boot partition **bootable**. It can be set by partition management tools, some software may call it "mark it **active**" or something.